# Bulk filling in contract forms

Tags: docusignapi

We have a standard contract that we want to send out.  We have the data all in a SQL database and want to insert that into the fields in the contract and send out.

So far I'm reading the Bulk sending but it looks like it just deals with signatures and no other data being inserted into the envelope document.

Does anyone know if there is any documentation on this?

Thanks.
Gary

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the way I would recommend to do this is to create a template and generate envelope from the templates. Then, for the resulting envelopes, you can update the form (tab) values from your code.
You will need to combine two different code examples to do this:

1. [Create the template.](https://developers.docusign.com/esign-rest-api/code-examples/code-example-create-template)
2. [Fill tab data in an envelope created from a template](https://developers.docusign.com/esign-rest-api/code-examples/set-template-tab-values) (you will loop and do this many times).

Comment: Thanks. We will try that.

Comment: Please mark this question as answered if you're good.